# Confluent Cloud - Add Basic Auth to Kafka Rest Proxy Docker Container

Tags: docker, confluent-platform, confluent-cloud

I have the requirement to run a Kafka Rest Proxy for my Confluent Cloud and would like to use the existing [Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest) that is provided by Confluent Cloud.

I got the Docker container running with the following command on my local machine:

```
docker run -p 8082:8082 --env-file env.list confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest
```

The env.file contains the following variables:

```
KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME=rest-proxy
KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS=http://0.0.0.0:8082
KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=<HIDDEN>
KAFKA_REST_CLIENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_BASIC_AUTH_USER_INFO=<HIDDEN>
KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=<HIDDEN>
KAFKA_REST_SECURITY_PROTOCOL=SASL_SSL
KAFKA_REST_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='<HIDDEN>' password='<HIDDEN>';
KAFKA_REST_SASL_MECHANISM=PLAIN
KAFKA_REST_CLIENT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=<HIDDEN>
KAFKA_REST_CLIENT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL=SASL_SSL
KAFKA_REST_CLIENT_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='<HIDDEN>' password='<HIDDEN>';
KAFKA_REST_CLIENT_SASL_MECHANISM=PLAIN
```

Following the [guide from Confluent Cloud for HTTP Basic Authentication](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/production-deployment/rest-proxy/security.html#http-basic-authentication) I need to add two files (`/etc/kafka-rest/rest-jaas.properties` and `/etc/kafka-rest/password.properties`) and some env variables for the basic auth to work.

I added the following variables to the env.file

```
KAFKA_REST_CLIENT_SASL_MECHANISM=PLAIN
KAFKA_REST_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD=BASIC
KAFKA_REST_AUTHENTICATION_REALM=KafkaRest
KAFKA_REST_AUTHENTICATION_ROLES=thisismyrole
KAFKAREST_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka-rest/rest-jaas.properties
```

And I created a new Docker image:

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:latest

COPY password.properties /etc/kafka-rest/
COPY rest-jaas.properties /etc/kafka-rest/

CMD ["/etc/confluent/docker/run"]
```

Running the new Docker image with `docker run -p 8082:8082 --env-file env.list my-image/cp-kafka-rest` the basic auth works...

...but now to my question:

Is it possible to get this working without having to create a new Docker image? I would like to avoid to have to maintain a new Docker image myself and just use the image provided by Confluent Cloud.